# Fotorama jQuery Gallery with Rails 4.2.0 (Turbolinks issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I've got the [Fotorama jQuery Slider](http://fotorama.io/) working; however, it doesn't work with [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) (and I'd rather not disable Turbolinks).

How can I make this jQuery slider load when the page that it's on is loaded through Turbolinks?

In `application.js` I've got the following code for dealing with Turbolinks:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
  // JavaScript to be triggered by Turbolinks/page:load event
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Can I add a function to this section of JavaScript to load the Fotorama slider?

Any ideas/feedback appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

I have never used this `Fotorama` slider but looking at its docs i think you can do this

```
$(document).on('ready page:load',function(){
   $('.fotorama').fotorama();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [JQuery-Turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem. I use it myself. Simply add it to the Gemfile, bundle update and you are good to go.